# Get GPS coordinates from new google maps

Tags: google-maps

how do I get GPS coordinates from new  Google maps. In old google maps I used to click right and select 'What's here' option which show me the GPS co ordinates but right click is not enabled in new maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. You simply click the location you want to get the GPS coordinates for and it will show you the complete address of the location with post code and GPS coordinates in the top left corner below the search bar.

[image]

But now it shows GPS coordinates in degrees and minutes so if you want to convert the format you can do it [here](http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_decimaldegrees.htm).

Comment: ohhh its funny.... it was not showing me any thing before but when I refreshed the page and clicked again it showed the coordinates.. thanks anyway... :)